# Single Table Row Data fetching in Hasura

Tags: graphql, hasura

Is there any way that I could insert data from single table multiple row's by using a single query as follows in Hasura.

Where the data1 and point1 are dynamic.

Input Example:

```
 
{ 
  "table1" : {
  
  id: "",
  name : "",
  value : "".
  result:
  {
    data1: "",
    point1: "",

    data2: "",
    point2: "",

  }
  
  

}
```

Comment: Your questions is not clear. What I understood is that you want to insert some data in columns( data, point) of the existing rows in that table. Or you just want to add multiple rows in a table in a single query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a mutation with parameters. Try to adapt the below to your needs:

```
mutation MyMutation($objects: [projects_insert_input!] = {}) {
  insert_table1(objects: $objects) {
    returning {
      id
      name
      value
      result
    }
  }
}
```

Parameters:

```
{
  "objects": {
      "id" : "myId",
      "name": "myName",
      "value": "myValue",
        "result":{
        "data":"Data1",
        "point":"Point1"
      }
  }
}
```

More info: https://hasura.io/learn/graphql/intro-graphql/graphql-mutations/